# Redux reducer for inserting into an array at a specific index

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I am trying to insert an array `questions` into a `state` array at a certain `index` in my array, however it is not always getting the order correct. I am expecting something like this:

```
[[/*arr 0*/], [/*arr 1*/], [/*arr 2*/], [/*arr 3*/], ...]
```

But I keep getting something like this:

```
[[/*arr 0*/], [/*arr 2*/], [/*arr 1*/], [/*arr 3*/], ...]
```

I tried following [this guide](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#inserting-and-removing-items-in-arrays) from the official Redux docs, but to no avail. My reducer is the following:

```
export const questions = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case SET_QUESTIONS:
            const {questions, index} = action.payload;

            let newArray = state.slice()
            newArray.splice(index, 0, questions);
            return newArray
        case RESET_QUESTIONS:
            return [];
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I have been asked to show how the actions are called, so here is the snippet where the actions are called. This loops about 7 times or so, depending on the length necessary. These calls are asynchronous, but I don't think this should necessarily change how the reducer functions.

```
axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_ENDPOINT}/getQuestionnaireData`, data).then(res => {
  store.dispatch(setQuestions(res.data, index));
  resolve();
}).catch(err => {
  store.dispatch(setError(true));
});
```

The dispatched action looks like this:

```
export const setQuestions = (questions, index) => ({
    type: SET_QUESTIONS,
    payload: {
        questions,
        index
    }
})
```

EDIT 2:

Because there was no way around the way that the dispatch calls are made (can't force insertions to be in order), and unfortunately none of the responses I got were able to solve my problem, I opted for a different solution. I ended up changing my reducer to the following:

```
export const questions = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case SET_QUESTIONS:
            const {questions, index} = action.payload;

            //Retrieve the previously stored state
            let newObj = {
                ...state,
            }

            //Create a new object at the step key if it doesn't exist
            if (!newObj[index]) newObj[index] = {};

            //Assign the value at the id key in the step object
            newObj[index] = questions;

            return newObj;
        case RESET_QUESTIONS:
            return {};
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

From there, I just ended up using Lodash to iterate over the object like an array. This approach proved to be pretty reliable, so that's what I stuck with.

Thanks to everyone for their answers. I hope they work for someone else who might come across this problem later.

Comment: Is index from `action.payload` referring to the correct position in `state`?

Comment: I think your issue might be in the way you are putting the action, since this code looks like I would expect. I tried calling `questions([[0],[2],[3]], { type: SET_QUESTIONS, payload: { questions: [1], index: 1}})` and it returned 0,1,2,3 as I would expect it to. Try showing us how you put the action.

Comment: I don't understand well your problem. Could you show an example of array "questions" and "state" in the problem ?

Comment: @Lusito I have added more details to my original question. hopefully this clears some things up

Comment: @khan Yes, the index is referring to the correct position in state, verified by console logs.

Comment: @NicholasDomenichini, can we see the entire loop where the `axios.post()` is being called? Also, if this is wrapped in a `new Promise`, can you post that as well? Where are you getting `index` and `resolve()`?

Comment: I have a feeling, that you are looping x times and in each iteration, you are calling the axios.post. But the post calls might not resolve in the order you called them. Some might finish earlier and some later. Resulting in wrong inserts.

Comment: @Lusito your suspicion of different resolve times for the axios calls is pretty much spot on... this is the cause of the problem. However, if I called them in order and waited for each one, it would take forever, so instead I need a reducer that can actually handle asynchronous insertions into the array and put them in the right places.

Comment: @NicholasDomenichini you can use `Promise.all([dataArray].map(data => axios.post(....` and will recieve your array of question in order you need

Comment: @GeorgiyDubrov has the right idea.. This way you would only set the state once (when the last request has finished). Will Jenkins answer from below has the issue, that it might give you an incomplete array, which could cause different issues.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are not using Spread operator so Use spread operator and you can read about spread operator from following [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Try  the following code

```
  export const questions = (state = [], action) => {
        switch (action.type){
            case SET_QUESTIONS:
                const {questions, index} = action.payload;
                return [
                    ...state.slice(0,index),
                    questions,
                    ...state.slice(index)
                  ]
            case RESET_QUESTIONS:
                return [];
            default:
                return state;
        }
    };
```

Comment: This does not work, and it also goes against what the official redux docs I linked above say to do. It explicitly says to not use this method, since it mutates the state directly.

Comment: @NicholasDomenichini can you share setQuestions() method

Comment: I have added the setQuestions method

Comment: @NicholasDomenichini the slice operation doesn't mutate anything. It creates a copy form an index to the other index exclusively. In the current example SET_QUESTIONS, creates a copy of an array of question returns it as a new state, the code may not work, but getting the idea of the slice should fix your problem

Comment: You don't need to use the spread operator. Using slice & splice is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Lusito `splice()` mutates original array, `slice()` doesn't.

Comment: @AlexanderKim, yes splice for itself is bad in a reducer, but slice + splice in combination is perfectly valid to use. (i.e. first copy the array by slicing, then modify the copy by splicing)

Answer (score 0):

You need to take account of the occasions (including the first time `SET_QUESTIONS` is dispatched) when your `state` array has fewer items in it than the new `index`.

Bearing that in mind, I'd probably do something like this:

```
export const questions = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_QUESTIONS:
      const { questions, index } = action.payload
      const stateCopy = [...state]
      stateCopy[index] = payload

      return stateCopy
    case RESET_QUESTIONS:
      return []
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```